# Mongoose Model : get fields displayed in all the document while retrieving even if fields are missing in saved collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Considering a collection, **photo** field is not defined in some documents. When I try to retrieve photo from the collection. I get the following response

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5757ea898a9d52801b98cc25"),
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5757ea898a934dsadsadsd25"),
"photo" : 'user.jpg'
}
```

Is there by chance I can get fields displayed in all the document even if it is missing (something like this)

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5757ea898a9d52801b98cc25"),
 "photo": undefined
}

{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5757ea898a934dsadsadsd25"),
 "photo" : 'user.jpg'
}
```

Comment: Not that I am aware.  What is your use-case?  It may be possible to insert a middleware (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) to do this for you... or maybe there is a better way to accomplish your goals.  You could also try just explicitly save documents with `undefined` keys

Comment: I did go through middleware, I did not find feasible. I am trying to handle data handling in Model class using Getters and render user with uniform data. 

_You could also try just explicitly save documents with undefined keys_ I am doing this for future instances, but there are several previous instances that are to be handled. Any suggestion regarding that

Comment: I would just write a script to iterate through all existing entries and update the model or write my views to not care

Comment: Just needed to add the default value to the key in the Schema definition. If data key is not available in the document, it returns the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Just required to add the default value to the key in the Schema definition. If data key is not available in the document, it returns the default value.